# Regex in google sheets - Extract parts of URL between slashes

Tags: regex, google-sheets, extract

I have difficulties with extracting parts of URL.

What I need is to know what category the product is(jeans, socks, tshirts), and a subcategory what color the product is(blue, black, white)

```
 https://www.examplewebsite.com/shop/jeans/blue/123456
 https://www.examplewebsite.com/shop/socks/black/234567
 https://www.examplewebsite.com/shop/tshirst/white/4321
```

What is the best way to extract this in google sheets?

Comment: Are you looking for a formula or a script? Have you already tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=index(split(A1,"/"),,4)
```

and

```
=index(split(A1,"/"),,5)
```

copied down to suit.

Comment: These formulas doesn't use [tag:regex] :)

Answer (score 0):

```
={"PRODUCT", "CATEGORY"; 
 INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A, "/"), , 4), 
 INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A, "/"), , 5)}
```

[image]